# JQuery animate - delay issue

Tags: jquery, menu, delay

I've got this site:

http://p33.yamandi.com/

Almost everything works fine, except one little annoying thing - the delay. If you click on Rossman menu item, then close it with "zamknij" icon and then try to click another menu item at once. You'll notice the 1-2 second delay. I have no idea what is the reason for this issue. It happens in all browsers. Can anyone help?

Regards, 
David

Comment: And another annoying thing are the language icons that stay in place even if the navigation is in animation ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is your problem, but try calling `stop()` before `animate()` on all the elements that you're animating. Something like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  mCustomScrollbars();
  $(function(){
    $("ul#menu a").click(function() {
      myId = this.id;
      $('.text').stop();
      $("ul#menu, h1#logo").stop().animate({left: '-=572'}, 500, function() {
        $("#lang").css("display", "none");
        $("#"+myId+"pr").stop().animate({left: 0}, 200);
        if(myId == "dojazd") {
          $("#outer-mapka").css("left", "50%").css("margin-left", "-213px");
        } else {
          api.goTo(myId.charAt(myId.length-1));
        }
      });
    });
    $("a.close").click(function() {
      api.goTo(1); 
      $(".text").stop().animate({left: "-=950"}, 200, function() { 
        $(".text, #outer-mapka").css("left", "-950px");
        $("ul#menu, h1#logo").stop().animate({left: '0'}, 500, function() {} );
        $("#lang").css("display", "block");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

While adding `stop()` before `animate()` will resolve the problem, it may be worth understanding the source of the problem.

In this case, the user observes a delay in the animation because multiple animations are in the queue before it.

One contributor to the queue backing up because the animation function complete call is executed once per animated element, not once for the animation as a whole.  In the following example, the complete call is invoked twice, which in turn invokes another animation, causing 4 animations to enter the queue.

For example:

```
$("ul#menu a").click(function() {
  myId = this.id;
  $("ul#menu, h1#logo").animate({left: '-=572'}, 500, function() {
    // This code will run twice, once when ul#menu finishes animating
    // and once when h1#logo finishes animating.  Is this the desired
    // behavior?  Is it safe to call api.goTo() twice?       
    $("#lang").css("display", "none");
    $("#"+myId+"pr").animate({left: 0}, 200);

    if(myId == "dojazd") {
      $("#outer-mapka").css("left", "50%").css("margin-left", "-213px");
    }
    else {      
      api.goTo(myId.charAt(myId.length-1));      
    }  
  });
});
```

Another contributor to the queue backup, and the primary contribution, is because of a generic selector.  In the following example, when a closed link is clicked, it causes all 7 text classes to animate, and when they complete, they cause 2 more animations.  Resulting in 21 animations:

```
$("a.close").click(function() {
  api.goTo(1);
  // The .text selector matches seven different elements.  Thus, a when
  // clicking the close link, seven animations are added to the queue.
  $(".text").animate({left: "-=950"}, 200, function() { 
    $(".text, #outer-mapka").css("left", "-950px");
    // And two more animations are added to the queue.
    $("ul#menu, h1#logo").animate({left: '0'}, 500, function() {} ); 
    $("#lang").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

Thus, when you clicked a menu, closed the page, then clicked the menu again, a delay could be observed waiting for the 21 animations to go through the queue.

To resolve this, one can use a flag to indicate if the complete function should run.  Additionally, being more specific on the selectors can help prevent unnecessary invocations.  Here is a possible solution implementing both:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  mCustomScrollbars();
  $(function(){         
    var menu_visible=true; // Flag to indicate if menu is visible.
    $("ul#menu a").click(function() {
      myId = this.id;      
      $("ul#menu, h1#logo").animate({left: '-=572'}, 500, function() {
          // If the menu is not visible, then return as this function has
          // already ran.
          if (!menu_visible) return;

          // Will be hiding the menu, so set the flag to false.
          menu_visible = false;

          $("#lang").css("display", "none");
          $("#"+myId+"pr").animate({left: 0}, 200);

          if(myId == "dojazd") {
            $("#outer-mapka").css("left", "50%").css("margin-left", "-213px");
          }
          else {          
            api.goTo(myId.charAt(myId.length-1));          
          }
        });
    });

    // For each text class.
    $(".text").each(function() {
      // Store a handle to the text.
      var $text=$(this);
      // Add a click event to a close link within the text.
      $("a.close", $text).click(function() {
        api.goTo(1); 
        // Only animate the text containing the close link.
        $text.animate({left: "-=950"}, 200, function() { 
          $(".text, #outer-mapka").css("left", "-950px");
          $("ul#menu, h1#logo").animate({left: '0'}, 500, function() {
            // The menu is visible so set the flag.
            menu_visible=true;
          }) ;
          $("#lang").css("display", "block");
        });
      });
    });  
  });
});
```